# Because me and my family or because I and my family

Tags: coordination, personal-pronouns, case, colloquial-language

What is correct?

> Because **me** and my family all lived our whole life in America and we just make visits.

or

> Because **I** and my family all lived our whole life in America and we just make visits.

Comment: See this **> [answer to a related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22620/2127) <**. In short, it would be okay in informal speech, but to be formally correct, you'd have to say "**my family and I**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because my family and I ...** in the subject part of a sentence (or **because of my family and me** in the predicate).

However, your sentence has issues beyond that.

**Because my family and I lived our whole lives in America, we have no intention of moving anywhere else. We will only go to China to visit.**